# Whats the Shortcut Key for inserting a Horitonzal Line <hr> in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Whats the Shortcut Key for inserting a Horitonzal Line`<hr>` in a message in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Without touching the mouse or going through the tideous menu every single time.

If NO keyboard shortcuts exist [as of yet], then:
1. How to **programm/hack** this in the configuration?
2. Are there **addons** that can bind menu items to a shortcut keystroke?

---

[image]

Comment: There isn't one, but you can do this two step keystroke `Alt + i` then just the letter `o`.

Comment: @Narzard You should put that in as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a direct shortcut, but it can be accomplished by sending two separate keystrokes.

First, use `Alt + i` to access the Insert Menu followed by `o` to insert a Horizontal line.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!  Eventhough its not a direct shortcut, still  +1 for "the best suggestion yet" :)

Comment: You could also get AutoHotkey and add a custom global keyboard shortcut for alt+i, o and bind it to something easier like (ctrl + a key that isn't used by that program).

Comment: @Nazard allrighty mate that nails it for me im gonna flag this as an answer :D thank you im gonna familiarize myself with that AutoHotkey then